# SSRS Subscriptions Duplicating email

Tags: sql-server-2008, email, reporting-services, exchange-server

Had an interesting error today and couldn't find anything online about it so wondered if any of you guys had seen this behavior before.

We had an out of memory error and the CPU usage was spiking this morning on our reports server, a clean reboot seemed to rectify the issue, however since then all the email subscriptions have been sending multiple times. What do i mean by this, the subscription as far as SSRS is concerned ran once at its normal time (10am), this has been proven by scrutinizing the logs to see if another execution occurred (it didn't) and by renaming the SPROC that the report references to ensure that it would fail, yet it didn't and the mail resent. I then checked the Exchange queues and turned on logging for the connection and i could see a new mail being resubmitted every 30mins to the exchange mail queue.

The question is, what process is causing that mail to be resubmitted to the exchange server and how, other than another reboot do we stop the emails resending.

Thanks in advance

-- Further --

Having done more digging we have noticed that the `[ReportServer].[dbo].Notifications` table is populated with all of the reports that are sending out multiple times with the Attempts column incrementing every time the duplicate email is sent out.

We still dont know why these are resending

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to be down to the logging level... If you switch the Report Server Service logging level down to level 2 (Exceptions, restarts and warnings) this error seems to manifest itself however when the logging level is switched back up to 3 or above the error seems to disappear. Some similar behavior is noticed here:  http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-NZ/sqlreportingservices/thread/b78bb6e2-0810-4afd-ba6b-8b09a243f349

Answer (score 0):

Check the SQL Agent jobs (named with GUIDs) for the subscriptions. Maybe the schedule on those go messed up somehow.

Comment: Thanks for your response Jamie. I've checked all the individual jobs and they hadn't re-ran. None of the physical subscriptions have re-run, it just seems to be the actual email resending to the exchange server...

Comment: The email isn't queued within SSRS, and SSRS (and SQL) don't even try to resend when there is a failure. So I think this is happening somewhere else. Take a look at what smtp server you have specified for SSRS, and look at that server, maybe.